# Sort Pandas dataframe and print highest n values

Tags: pandas, sorting, dataframe, max

I have a pandas data frame and I want to sort column('Bytes') in Descending order and print highest 10 values and its related "Client IP" column value. Suppose following is a part of my dataframe. I have many different methods and failed?

```
0       Bytes    Client Ip                
0       1000      192.168.10.2    
1       2000      192.168.10.12    
2       500       192.168.10.4     
3       159       192.168.10.56
```

Following prints only the raw which has the highest value.

```
print df['Bytes'].argmax()
```

Answer (score 44):

I think you can use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) (New in `pandas` version `0.17.0`):

```
print df
   0  Bytes  Client             Ip
0  1      1    1000   192.168.10.2
1  0      0    2000  192.168.10.12
2  2      2     500   192.168.10.4
3  3      3     159  192.168.10.56

print df.nlargest(3, 'Client')
   0  Bytes  Client             Ip
1  0      0    2000  192.168.10.12
0  1      1    1000   192.168.10.2
2  2      2     500   192.168.10.4
```

Answer (score 28):

**Note:** `sort` is deprecated - use `sort_values` instead

To [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) descending use `ascending=False`:

```
In [6]: df.sort('Bytes', ascending=False)
Out[6]:
   0  Bytes      Client Ip
1  1   2000  192.168.10.12
0  0   1000   192.168.10.2
2  2    500   192.168.10.4
3  3    159  192.168.10.56
```

*To take the first 10 values use [`.head(10)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html).*

Comment: There are 10 columns in the dataframe. I want to print only the highest 10 values in "Bytes" column and and its related "Client IP" column value?

Comment: So: `df.sort('Bytes', ascending=False).head(10)` ? or `df.sort('Bytes', ascending=False).head(10)[['Bytes, 'Client Ip']]` ...

Comment: these are the values that I get? They are not sorted?
           9977   
           9977  
           9977      
            9977  
             9972   
           9968  
           9968   
           9968    
          99604

Comment: I found this in some place, how can i adjust it...DataFrame({'count' : bt.groupby( [ "Bytes", "Client IP"] ).size()}).reset_index().head(10)                                     @Andy Hayden ok Thanks.

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage they are not integers :) (it is sorting the strings lexigraphically). You need to force the Bytes column to integers, e.g. df['Bytes'] = df['Bytes'].astype(int).

Comment: I have used a smaller version of the data file and following is the output. Why it not sorted?print df.sort('Bytes Returned', ascending=False).head(10)[['Bytes Returned', 'Client-IP']] `                                                                         Bytes   Client-IP
3           9848  61.245.172.12
4           4985  61.245.172.14
0           4482  61.245.172.14
8          35535   61.245.172.1
1           3094  61.245.172.14
6           2282  61.245.172.14
2          20037  61.245.172.14
5           1498  61.245.172.12
7           1048  61.245.172.14 `

Comment: It still looks like it's sorting lexicographically, did you force the Bytes column to integers?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage you can mark this answer as correct and upvote if it helped :) Happy panda-ing!

Answer (score 3):

```
df['Bytes'] = df['Bytes'].astype('int')
print df.sort('Bytes', ascending=False).head(10)[['Bytes', 'Client-IP']]
```

I could solve it using above code with the help of Andy Hayden. :D

Comment: This worked because your Bytes column was (incorrectly) stored as strings, something isn't quite right in the way you are reading into your DataFrame. This part shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
df[['Bytes', 'Client Ip']].sort_values('Bytes', ascending=False).nlargest(10, 'Bytes')
```

This should get you everything you need 
1) Sorting Bytes
2) Returning the Largest 10 Bytes values